# add group of checkboxes to a prestashop product

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a prestashop site set up, the products sold are sandwiches, what I need to do is add for each sandwiches (product)

two groups of check-box (and not radio as you can do with attributes)

one for the sauce ex. "mustard, mayonnaise, ketchup etc... "

and one for the accompaniments ex "salad, carrots, cucumbers etc....."

the client (on the front end) must be able to select any sauce and any accompaniments combinations that's why I need check-box. the selected choice will have no effect on the price but need to be shown on the order.

I added a field on the ps_product database that hold all the sauces separated by ", " and I am able to display them as check-box on the product page editing the product.tpl of my template like so:

```
{assign var=sauces value=", "|explode:$product->sauce}

<fieldset class="attribute_fieldset">

    {foreach from=$sauces item=foo}
        <label class="attribute_label" for="{$foo}">
            {$foo} 
            <input id="{$foo}" type="checkbox" name="{$foo}" value="{$foo}" />
        </label> 

    {/foreach}

</fieldset>
```

i put That block of code in the  so it gets added after my other attributes

but i can't figure how to save the choice when the product is added to the cart,

i tried overwriting the cart.php class and CartController.php with no luck so far i'am not sure when or where that form is being processed before it gets added to the cart, i would like to simply append the values of the selected checkbox to the description of the product when it's added to the cart so it keeps that description trough all the order process and trough the invoice and e-mail sent.

Thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 0):

It may brick your system 
Try Prestashop override function to do that
by

Comment: Admin>Catalog>Product Attribute //add an attribute and its value

Comment: Yeah i did it that way (with override and attribute) but it's not really what i need since i can't display the attributes as check-boxes (or am I missing something?), but displaying these groups of attributes I made into groups of check-boxes (that doesn't event need to change the price) is just what I am after